# Npm start errors

Tags: angular, npm, localhost, npm-start

I am starting to do some Angular tutorials and I cannot get npm to  start on OSX Yosemite.

Below is the error log. I appeared to have followed the instructions but cannot see the compiled app at localhost:3000.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'lite' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.8
3 info using node@v4.4.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelite', 'lite', 'postlite' ]
5 info prelite media-watch-list@1.0.0
6 info lite media-watch-list@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info media-watch-list@1.0.0 Failed to exec lite script
9 verbose stack Error: media-watch-list@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid media-watch-list@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd /Users/ross/Sites/lynda/exercisefiles/c2/02-01-start
12 error Darwin 14.5.0
13 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
14 error node v4.4.7
15 error npm  v2.15.8
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error media-watch-list@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the media-watch-list@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the media-watch-list package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     lite-server
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs media-watch-list
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls media-watch-list
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed. The real problem was not in connecting to localhost:3000,
    but was that rails wasn't installed correctly. 
    When I ran "rails server" there was an error line that said:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.1/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb: 
No source of timezone data could be found. 

Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenot found for help resolving this error. 

The link to the solution is: 
https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo%3a%3a
DataSourceNotFound-Errors I think this is a common error in Windows machine.
```